# Send stored procedure in ajax data

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I need send stored procedure with parameter in ajax data.

Below is my example, after send get this [error](http://prntscr.com/alikkx)

Apostrophes real problem,any solution?

```
function sendData(userNameVal, procedureNameVal, jsonCallBackFunc) {
    var stringVal = "wsInsertData N'EXECUTE carInsert N''160655'',N''data:image/png;base64,AAAAAAAAAAAA'',N''18602''', N'18602'";

     $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: 'helloService.asmx/myService',
                    data: "{userName:\"" + userNameVal + "\",procedureName:\"" + stringVal + "\",callback:\"" + jsonCallBackFunc + "\",}",

                    dataType: 'json',
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    success: function (response) {
                        $('#lblError').html(JSON.stringify(response));
                    },
                    error: function (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    }
                });
            }
```

Comment: Passing raw SQL seems like a catastrophically bad idea. Pass an identifier mapped to the sp name on the server side along with the parameters and construct a parametrized command there.

Comment: Consider using [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to get the `data` as string

Answer (score 1):

Security! All it takes is a user to edit the JSON response to the server and add their own SQL, and they can make your SQL server do anything they want. Pass whatever parameters you need, and have the server construct the Stored Proc after sanitizing possible crazy inputs from the client.

Answer (score 0):

Before 'callback' you add a single quote ', which is not terminated.

Comment: It needed a fix anyway :-). It might have something to do with the value of jsonCallBackFunc, but before spending much more effort on this, I suggest to take Alex K.'s advice: it is a very bad idea to pass sql to the server, so you may not run into this problem once you've solved your - much more important - security problem.